# Placing word documents into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a couple word documents and i want to collate their contents into a data frame before exporting into an excel. So far i have this code:

```
import docx2txt

my_word_files = glob.glob(r"C:\Users\.......\*.docx")

for file in my_word_files:
    word = docx2txt.process(file)
```

This turns the word documents into strings and the contents look like the below:

Questions

: What is your full name?

<ANSWER_1>

John Smith

<ANSWER_1>

etc....

Each question starts with a ':' and each answer is wrapped inbetween two <ANSWER_...>. What i want to do is turn it onto a dataframe which would look like the below:

```
What is your full name?   Question2    Question3   etc...
John Smith                Answer2      Answer3
```

With each row being the answers from each word file so that everything is collated nicely.

Comment: 100% that each question starts with a `:` what about multiple answers?

Comment: @Manakin Yes each question starts with: and there are no multiple answers

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are starting with a pandas dataframe, we can apply some logical operations before pivoting to your desired output.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

d = """: What is your full name?

<ANSWER_1>

John Smith

<ANSWER_1>
: What is your Age
<ANSWER_1>
25
<ANSWER_1>
<ANSWER_1>
: Where are you located
<ANSWER_1>
London, fam.
<ANSWER_1>
<ANSWER_2>
Engurrland
<ANSWER_2>

"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(d),sep='\t',header=None)
```

First, let's build a sequence so we can have a logical order of question + answers and remove any  values with `<>` in the body.

```
df = df[~df[0].str.contains('<|>')]

df['sequence'] = df.groupby(df[0].str.contains('^:').cumsum()).cumcount()

df['questionSequence'] = np.where(
    df[0].str.contains("^:"), df.groupby(df[0].str.contains("^:")).cumcount(), np.nan
)

df['questionSequence'] = df['questionSequence'].ffill()

print(df)

                          0     sequence  questionSequence
0   : What is your full name?         0               0.0
2                  John Smith         1               0.0
4          : What is your Age         0               1.0
6                          25         1               1.0
9     : Where are you located         0               2.0
11               London, fam.         1               2.0
14                 Engurrland         2               2.0
```

Next, we want to split out the Question column to create a separate question & answer column and remove the pesky colon while we are at it.

```
df['question'] = np.where(df['sequence'].eq(0),df[0],np.nan)
df['question'] = df['question'].ffill().str.strip(': ')
```

This is shaping up quite nicely, now lets filter out the questions from column `0` by filtering on the sequence column.

```
df1 = df1 = df[(df['sequence'].ne(0))].copy()

print(df1)

              0    sequence  questionSequence                 question
2     John Smith         1               0.0  What is your full name?
6             25         1               1.0         What is your Age
11  London, fam.         1               2.0    Where are you located
14    Engurrland         2               2.0    Where are you located
```

Finally, we will use a multi index to create your pivot in the same order of the questions.

```
final = pd.crosstab(
    df1["sequence"], [df1["questionSequence"], df1["question"]], df1[0], aggfunc="first"
)
```

[image]